# ¿Cómo hacer una función en java, que permute una cadena?

Tags: java, string, funciones

¿Como hacer eta función en java?, que permute una cadena, y que se guarde en una variable, tal como en la librería random, bueno pero esta genera números al azar. Lo que busco es algo sencillo, solo permutar una cadena.

**Por ejemplo**

Mi cadena base a permutar es *ABCDEFGHIJKL*, ahora con esa misma cadena distintas permutaciones, retornando la string permutada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías simplemente usar indices aleatorios para desordenar el arreglo de caracteres que representa el `String`, parecido a un algoritmo de ordenamiento.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Desordenador {

    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    private char[] car;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Desordenador d = new Desordenador("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(d.desordenar());
        }


    }

    // en el constructor guardemos el arreglo de caracteres.
    public Desordenador(String origen){
        this.car = origen.toCharArray();
    }

    // cambiemos pares de caracteres algunas veces (3*tamaño parece bien)
    public String desordenar(){
        for (int i = 0;i<3*car.length;i++){
            cambioAleatorio();
        }
        return new String(car);
    }

    // cambia dos caracteres aleatorios del arreglo
    public void cambioAleatorio(){
        int a = sr.nextInt(car.length);
        int b = sr.nextInt(car.length);
        char c = car[a];
        car[a] = car[b];
        car[b] = c;
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
GNPJELAHKBMCDIFO
EIPLMDONKABHGCJF
MBIOAPEKFJNHLCGD
KCJPDFIHOBGLNEMA
HPFMKCIAEBGONDLJ
NAHJGCDMBELOIPFK
ACBHEDLPMNOGFJIK
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, agradezco que te tomes el tiempo. :D